# How to get client machine details and location details in PHP

Tags: php, geolocation, ip, country-codes

Here i want to do suppose i am have domain,who all are coming domain i want to get their **ip address** and **city** and **state** and ***locality*** and **country**, i have tried but i can able to get only two datas like `ip` and 'country' but for me remaining data's also i need, how can achieve this ?

```
<?php
function ip_visitor_country()
{
    $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $country  = "Unknown";

    if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $client;
    }
    elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $forward;
    }
    else
    {
        $ip = $remote;
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=".$ip);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $ip_data_in = curl_exec($ch); // string
    curl_close($ch);

    $ip_data = json_decode($ip_data_in,true);
    $ip_data = str_replace('&quot;', '"', $ip_data); // for PHP 5.2 see stackoverflow.com/questions/3110487/

    if($ip_data && $ip_data['geoplugin_countryName'] != null) {
        $country = $ip_data['geoplugin_countryName'];
    }

    return 'IP: '.$ip.' # Country: '.$country;
}

echo ip_visitor_country(); // output Coutry name

?>
```

Comment: Well, if you look at the returned data, there is `geoplugin_city` and `geoplugin_region`, so you'd get those the same way as `geoplugin_countryName`. Just note that it may not always return all of the data, which is a limitation of their API.

Comment: @aynber, Can you please update your code

Comment: It's not my code, it's yours. But all you need to do is copy the same code that you use to get the countryName, and change the field names to what you're getting from the json response.